# Wix v3 to Wix v4 no Product-tag anymore?

Tags: wix, wix4

The code below which I borrowed as an example from https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5610 is for Wix v3. (don't know if the code works, it is about the file structure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="WiXv3_Setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="SeaRisen LLC" UpgradeCode="71b53809-790d-483b-8ce8-d8f52c746b22">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WiXv3_Setup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WiXv3_Setup" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                
      <File Source="$(var.ToClipboard.TargetPath)" />
            <!-- </Component> -->
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

We clearly see a structure `Wix > Product > Package`

When starting a Wix v4 project using

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
```

It seems that `<Product>` is not allowed anymore under `Wix` tag.

I could not find any documentation about this if `<Product>` not anymore supported in Wix v4. Am I missing an extension?
For now I've removed `<Product>` from `<Wix> > <Product> > <Package>`-tag and changed it to `<Package>` so that it becomes `<Wix> > <Package>`.

Is this correct to drop `<Product>` tag and wrap everything in a `<Package>` tag?

`<Product>` tag allowed the use of a `<Conditions>` tag, how do we use this now with `<Package>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Product` and `Package` elements in WiX v3 were combined and simplified in WiX v4.

Comment: I thought so, thanks to confirm. any documentation on what changed regarding Product and Package ?

Comment: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/package/

Comment: I've found that indeed, but no info on why Product is not anymore avaible and why they were merged and what properties set on Product should be used now on Package etc.. (found it myself now but might help others...) Wix v4 documentation is a bit lacking when coming from v3. most documentation still points to v4 but some things have been changed.

Comment: The why is to make it simpler. You can convert v3 authoring to v4 using HeatWave or `wix convert`.